# two Different color for saparate list in android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, arraylist, adapter

I have three ArrayList, i.e A, B, C. I merged ArrayList A and ArrayList B into ArrayList C (empty). I am able to display all the elements from both A and B. My problem is I want to dispaly elements from A in green color and elements from B in greay color. My code is like this

```
private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    LayoutInflater mInflator;   

    boolean flag;
    boolean flag1; 

    public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> aList) {

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     super();
     mInflator = TrackDevices.this.getLayoutInflater(null);

     cArrayList = aList;

     flag = cArrayList.addAll(aArrayList);

         flag1 = cArrayList.addAll(bArrayList);      

  }   

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(view == null){

    view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.track_frag, null);                
    holder.deviceTag = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.track);             

    if(flag){
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }else if(flag1){
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }               

    view.setTag(holder);

      }else{                

        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
      }

        BluetoothDevice device = cArrayList.get(position);
            final String deviceName = device.getAddress();
            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0){

                holder.deviceTag.setText(deviceName);

            }else{              
            holder.deviceTag.setText("No devices");
        }

            return view;
        }

     }
```

Above code is always showing in green color for both A and B elements in C arraylist. How to make different for each list.

Comment: Why negative vote for this question? What is wrong

Comment: BluetoothDevice is your pojo class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the size property of arrylist,

```
int flag=A.size();
```

and in your getview method do it like this:-

```
 if(position<flag)
 {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
else 
{
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
}
```

Comment: There might be a chances of both list size should be same. Then how to do

Comment: you have added arraylists A and B into C,so first C will be null now lets assume that A has 10 elements so you add A into C now C has 10 elements,now we assume that B also has 10 elements and we add that too into C so now C has 20 elements what i have done is flag=A.size(),so for the C arraylist till A's element it will provide Green color and after that gray.I hope that you will understand with this explanation,if i helped accept this answer

Comment: good logic. How to do same thing for third row(another arraylist)

Comment: u there @Pramod Yadav

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm imagining the `flag` variable is determined as a function of the position. It's not obvious where this property is set.

Since you're using the ViewHolder "pattern", do not set position dependent logic when you create the view. Instead, set them **after** you've determined which view to use (either a new one or one that already existed). Remember, when you're using ViewHolders, you're re-using views. This means your view will be recycled and reused at differing positions and therefore, any logic that has anything to do with the positioning of the items (or their content) should be determined after the view has been created or recycled.

In practice, change the positioning of your setBackgroudnColor lines:

```
if(view == null){

...
/* REMOVE THIS FROM HERE 
if(flag){
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}else if(flag1){
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
}               
*/
}else{                
    ...
    holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
}

// ADD IT HERE: (After you've determined the view)
if(flag){
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}else if(flag1){
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
}
```